# Insist that vs Insist on that

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I have heard both variant used:

- I insist on that he does his homework now.
- I insist that he does his homework now.

Which is correct?

Is the following sentence without prepositions grammatical?

- I insist he does his homework now.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, a that-clause cannot be a complement of a preposition. So I would say the first one is ungrammatical.

Comment: Yes, the final sentence is grammatical. or *I insist on him doing his homework now*.

Answer (score 1):

The form "insist on" is used with nouns and noun phrases; whereas "insist" alone is used to with finite clauses (clauses that can be sentences on their own).

For the three examples that you gave, two are grammatical:

- I insist that he does his homework now.
- I insist he does his homework now.

These are both okay, because "that" is usually optional when used to introduce a finite relative clause.

The other example is not:

- I insist on that he does his homework now.

This is not grammatical because "that he does his homework now" is not a noun phrase. As in Tᴚoɯɐuo's example, you could turn the latter part of the sentence into a noun phrase with "I insist on him doing his homework now".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> I insist that he do his homework now.

because we use subjunctive. or else:

> I insist on him doing his homework now.

Comment: Can you give some sources to back that up and clarify how it adds to the existing answer?